# C - Why does puts behave unexpectedly, but printf does not when using scanf?

Tags: c

I was testing some code earlier that looked like this:

```
char input;
int data;

while(scanf("%c %d", &input, &data) != EOF) {
    puts("foo");
}
```

And when I read it with the following input:

```
c 8
c 10
c 15
c 18
^D
```

This was my output:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Although I was only really expecting to have `foo` printed once; that is, once the EOF signal was sent. I also tried running it outside my IDE and manually in the terminal (because CLion has issues with EOF), and when I ran it manually through the terminal, foo would print once after the first input, and then double print each time after.

However, when I use `printf` instead of `puts` inside the loop, my code runs as expected. I want to know **why** puts was causing an issue here? I imagine it has something to do with the IO stream, but I am not exactly sure why this is happening.

Is this undefined behavior? If so, why is that happening?

**EDIT**: Someone in the comments said that they were not getting the same issue. I've attached a screenshot of my code + terminal.
I am also running gcc-9.4 if that makes any difference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwzno.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior -- `printf` behaves the same as `puts` for me. I see no explanation why it should do otherwise; perhaps something unrelated is wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your observation.

Comment: I would have written `while(scanf(" %c%d", &input, &data) == 2)` note the change in the space character position too. It is essential to know how `scanf` treats whitespace with different format specifiers (in the format string *and* in the input), and what it returns.

Comment: There is no "EOF signal".  When the input stream is closed, scanf returns an integer value (almost certainly -1) which is represented to the C pre-processor by the token EOF and referred to in documentation as "EOF".   It's not a signal of any kind.  It's just the integer value that scanf returns when the file it is reading from has no more data.

Comment: `scanf` rule 1: Its return value on success is the number of successfully converted inputs.  So check for that (2 in this case) — do *not* just check for 1/0/EOF.  `scanf` rule 2: `%c` is subtly different.  Either don't use it all, or *always* put a space in front of it: `" %c %d"`.  Only use `%c` without a space if you *really* know what you're doing (although in that case, you might as well just use `getchar`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root of the problem is that `%c` does not skip over leading whitespace.

Here's what's happening - your input stream contains the following sequence:

```
{ 'c', ' ', 8, '\n', 'c', ' ', 10, '\n', 'c', ' ', 15, '\n', 'c', ' ', 18, '\n' }
```

The first call to `scanf` reads `'c'` into `input` and 8 into `data` and returns `2` (for two successful conversions and assignments).  The *next* call to `scanf` reads `'\n'` into `input` and *tries* to read `'c'` into `data` - that's a matching failure, so `data` isn't assigned.  However, since `'\n'` was successfully read into `input`, `scanf` returns `1` (which is not `EOF`).  The next call to `scanf` reads `' '` into `input` and `10` into `data`.

Lather, rinse, repeat.  Depending on where you are in the sequence, `scanf` will return `2`, `1`, or `0`, none of which are the same as `EOF`.  This is why you get multiple `foo` outputs per line, because you're not reading what you think you're reading.

There are two things you need to do to fix this:

1. Put a blank in front of the `%c` specifier - this will tell `scanf` to skip over leading whitespace;
2. Instead of testing against `EOF`, test against `2` - you are expecting 2 successful conversions and assignments per input line:

```
while ( scanf( " %c %d", &input, &data ) == 2 )
  puts( "foo" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare to EOF, count the number of valid conversions.  In particular, on the input you show:

```
scanf("%c %d", &input, &data)
```

will read the first `c` into `input`, assign the value 8 to `data`, and return 2.  The next character in the input stream is `\n`, so the second `scanf` stores that in `input` and is unable to get an integer value out of `c`, so it does not write anything to `data` and returns 1.  The next call to `scanf` writes `c` to `input` and sets `data` to 10.  Rinse and repeat.

You probably meant to write:

```
while(scanf(" %c %d", &input, &data) == 2) {
```

(note the space before the `%c`).

Answer (score 1):

After the first line, `"%c %d"` is consuming the prior line's `'\n'` and then chokes on `'c'` as an `int`, necessitating another loop to process the *line*.

- Use a leading space to consume whitespace.
- Check results.

---

```
// while(scanf("%c %d", &input, &data) != EOF) {
int count;
while((count = scanf(" %c %d", &input, &data)) != EOF) {
  printf("count:%d input:%c data:%d\n", 
      count, count >= 1 ? input : '?', count >= 2 ? data : -1);
}
```